# Data Transfer between iOS and PC over WiFi

Tags: ios, windows, networking, wifi

I Need to create an iOS application and a PC application, the two need to be able to exchange data over Wi-Fi (either direct or via a wifi router).

The iOS app will act as a remote control for some of the features of the PC app, for instance, if a video is playing on the pc application then the iOS app will have buttons to control playback on the PC such as play, pause, stop etc, when one of these buttons is pressed then I need to send some bytes to the pc over wifi.

My questions are:

- how should I go about sending data - Wifi direct or via wifi network that both devices are connected to?
- can anyone help with example code to connect or send data to a specific device over wifi for either methods?

to be clear, I don't need help with creating the applications themselves - only the wireless transfer of data between the devices using the Wi-Fi radio whether it be direct or via a router.

The main question: is it possible to initiate a connection/send bytes under iOS over wi-fi to a pc on the same network or via wifi direct?

Help with the method to do this or example code would be helpful.

Comment: You were probably down voted because you show no attempt at solving the problem yourself. A simple search will answer your "Main Question" (the answer to which, by the way, is Yes). The bigger issue here is that you seemingly lack a lot of background knowledge as to how connections between devices work. Perhaps you should focus on that first, once you've grasped the basics, you'll find that successive quests for knowledge will lead to an answer. You can look here for inspiration http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Comment: I haven't attempted myself because I don't know where to start, that's why I'm asking for help. I couldn't find a single example of this type of connection and I spent a day searching online. I have never used wi-fi in software before however I have quite a bit of experience with Bluetooth connections after my last project, but this doesn't appear similar.

Comment: If you hover over the down vote button you'll see it states "This question does not show any research effort ..." hence you were down voted previously. A simple Google of "socket connections in ios" will yield more answers than you'll know what to do with.